# Is there a way to get the firstname and the lastname from firebaseauth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase authentication in my project. I know you can use firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName to get the first name and the last name together. But is there any way to get the first name and the last name separately? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to get the separate first name and last name from Firebase Authentication.

You could try getting the 'first' and 'last' names by splitting the spaces (`name.split(" ")`), but this probably won't be a good idea since there are languages such as Japanese, where the names might not have spaces. ([Reference](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names))

Answer (score 1):

Why no trim by spaces?

```
var fullname = ...
var surname = fullname.split(" ").getOrNull(1);
```

Check if surname is null before you use it.

The index for first name is 0, and it usually won't be null.